# Export highlighted region from Google Map

Tags: google-maps

Is there any way to export the hightlighted region (the dotted red) (see figure below) in kml format? or do i have to to use google earth? if so what is the method? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0xCi.png)

I tried using My Map in Google but that is not what I expected because I still need to digitize the region, hence the accuracy might slightly incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Google Maps doesn't allow KML exports (nor any other exports for that matter).

Instead check out [Overture Maps](https://overturemaps.org/) or [Open Street Maps](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) — esp. [How can I export a large zone from OpenStreetMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273036/how-can-i-export-a-large-zone-from-openstreetmap)